# What happens if I rebase -i across two commits which have a merge in the middle?

Tags: git

I have a branch which has some commits like this....

````
1.5
1.4
1.3
2      <---  at this point I performed a ```merge otherbranch```
1.2
1.1
````

What I want to do it :

```
git rebase -i 1.1
```

Then I want to squash down my commits to 1.1 as a single commit. Assuming '2' has been merged with master what happens if I then try and merge my branch into master?

Comment: Clone the repo to a new folder, then try and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special. A merge commit is simply a commit (with more than one parent, but that's only a superficial difference here). If you merge back into master, git will still simply find a common ancestor and do the usual merge operation. git does not care where the 3 commits involved in the merge come from.

In other words, it just depends on which files (or more exact, which lines in which files) were changed in the two merge parents. If they overlap => conflicts as per usual. If they don't => no conflicts.

Comment: It's worth noting that `git rebase` normally *omits* merge commits entirely from the rebase process.  In this case, that's just what the OP wants (skip the merge now, redo it after rebase finishes copying the other commits).